# Find the derivative of $\ln |x|$

Tags: calculus

I am not sure about my answer, my first thought was that if the derivative existed, it would be a piece-wise function but after spliting the function, I only have one case $\frac{d\ln |x|}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$. Is this right?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396669/finding-the-derivative-of-an-absolute-value

Comment: Actually, the function $f(x) = \ln|x|$ is smooth since the only point that is troublesome for the absolute value does not belong to the domain of the natural logarithm. So yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

> $\frac{d\ln |x|}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$ Is this right?

Yes.

As a rule, the derivative of an even function (one that satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$) is an odd function (one that satisfies $f(-x) = -f(x)$) and vice versa.  This necessary condition is satisfied in your case: $\ln|x|$ is even whereas $1/x$ is odd.